# How can I install applications like Google Earth, NetBeans and Java?

Tags: 14.04, package-management, software-installation

I am new to Ubuntu.

1. I need Java 8 & NetBeans but cannot install. I tried by downloading something, but it did not get installed.
2. I tried same way for Google Earth, but it is also not installed.
3. First I tried Ubuntu 13.x (32 bit), but had same issue after I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (64-bit).

Where can I got to get good advice on installation of software, and for using Ubuntu effectively?

Comment: your question contains multiple question at once, for installing java 1.8 look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre

Comment: have a look at [How to install software on Ubuntu for a Windows User](http://askubuntu.com/a/575161/344926)...

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to install Java 8 and NetBeans is to download a single package containing both of them from the official Oracle website. The package is called [Java SE and NetBeans Cobundle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/jdk-netbeans-jsp-142931.html) and the version of Java SE and NetBeans Cobundle that you need to download is Linux x64.

The installation instructions for the Java SE and NetBeans Cobundle are the familiar click Next, Next... Install, and Finish type of instructions. These are the official Java SE and NetBeans Cobundle installation instructions from the [Oracle Java SE Development Kit 8 Update 40 and NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 Java SE Software Bundle Installation Instructions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/install-jdk6-22nb691-177131.html) webpage with minor revisions to make them specific to your question.

#### Installation Instructions

1. Download the installer file and save it on your system. For the 64-bit Linux operating system, the installer file name is `jdk-8u40-nb-8_0_2-linux-x64.sh`  Make sure that the file name has jdk-8 in it, so that way you know that you are downloading the installer for Oracle Java 8 SE and NetBeans 8.
2. Navigate to the directory into which you downloaded the installer file (example: `cd ~/Downloads/`) and type:

   ```
    sudo chmod +x jdk-8u40-nb-8_0_2-linux-x64.sh
   ```

   to change the installer file's permissions so it can be executed.
3. Type the following command from the directory where you placed the installation file:

   ```
    sudo ./jdk-8u40-nb-8_0_2-linux-x64.sh
   ```
4. At the Welcome page of the installation wizard, click *Next*.
5. JUnit is a unit testing framework for the Java programming language. At the JUnit License Agreement page, decide if you want to install JUnit and click the appropriate option, click *Next*.
6. At the JDK Installation page, specify the directory where to install the JDK and click *Next*.
7. At the NetBeans IDE Installation page, do the following:

- Specify the directory for the NetBeans IDE installation.
- Accept the default JDK installation to use with the IDE or specify another JDK location.

8. Click *Next*.
9. Review the Summary page to ensure the software installation locations are correct.
10. Click *Install* to begin the installation.
11. At the Setup Complete page, provide anonymous usage data if desired, and click *Finish*.

---

#### Google Earth

1. Visit the official [Download the latest version of Google Earth for PC, Mac, or Linux](http://www.google.com/earth/download/ge/agree.html) website.
2. Select the version of Google Earth that is compatible with your operating system. In your case, from the **Please select your download package** menu select *64 bit .deb (For Debian/Ubuntu)*
3. Click the **Agree and Download** button to start downloading Google Earth.
4. Browse in the Files file manager to the folder where the Google Earth file that you downloaded is located. The name of the Google Earth file is *google-earth-stable_current_amd64.deb*
5. Double click the google-earth-stable_current_amd64.deb file to open it for installation in the Ubuntu Software Center, or from the terminal change directories with `cd` to the directory where the Google Earth file that you downloaded is located and install it with this command:

   ```
    sudo apt install ./google-earth-stable_current_amd64.deb
   ```
6. Install Google Earth from the Ubuntu Software Center the same way that you would install any other package -- by clicking the *Install* button.

Comment: That's why I left a comment and asked you to have a look instead of answering!  :P  ;-)  Comment deleted, explanation accepted...

Comment: netbean 8 has been installed

Answer (score 1):

1. The terminal provides an easy way to download software and install it.

   Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> aund enter the following.

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
   sudo apt-get install netbeans
   ```
2. [This link](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/install-google-earth-in-ubuntu-1404.html) might be helpful.

The last question I do not understand. "proper reference" in what sense?

Comment: error occure :::     studio@studio-desktop:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer sudo apt-get install netbeans
Error: need a single repository as argument

Comment: One command at a time :)

Comment: For beginning Windows users, you should [let them use the software repository](http://askubuntu.com/a/575161/344926) first!  You're way too smart!  Dumb yourself down a bit!  ;-)  (correct answer, so still upvoted)