# Java Web option is not available in NetBeans 7.0.1

Tags: java, netbeans

I have installed NetBeans 7.0.1 from the Ubuntu Software Center, but when I go to create a project then the Java Web option is not displayed in the popup. Please give me an idea for how to solve this problem.

Comment: ubuntu make should help with this sort of thing.  umake it's called.

Answer (score 3):

I also tried to install NetBeans IDE 7.0.1 in Ubuntu 14.04 with OpenJDK Development Kit 7 and had the same problem as you have. I searched for a solution and found a Launchpad bug report: [Bug #1360100: NetBeans IDE cannot create a project](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netbeans/+bug/1360100), so I gave up and installed IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition from the Ubuntu Software Center instead. IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition is a free (it doesn't cost any money) and open source version of IntelliJ IDEA, a premier IDE for Java, Groovy, Scala and Android applications development.

Eclipse has most of the functionality of NetBeans in one form or another. Or you can download the Oracle Java 8 SE bundle of NetBeans IDE from the Oracle website, which contains both Java 8 and NetBeans 8. The instructions for installing the Java 8 SE and NetBeans Cobundle are at [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/608667/problem-with-installing-softwares/608699#608699).

NetBeans has been dropped from the default Ubuntu repositories in Ubuntu 15.04, so you need to download NetBeans in order to install it in Ubuntu 15.04. In Ubuntu 15.10 and later NetBeans 8.0 can be installed directly from the default Ubuntu repositories. NetBeans 8 targets Java 8 as its compatible Java version. In Ubuntu 18.04-20.10 NetBeans 10.0 can be installed directly from the default Ubuntu repositories. In Ubuntu 21.04-22.04 NetBeans 12.0 can be installed directly from the default Ubuntu repositories.